# ASP.net membership provider - Can I switch from Microsoft Access to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-membership

The asp.net membership provider uses access database.

Would it be possible to use a mssql server to store this instead?

Seems odd for me to use a seperate access db instead of putting everything inside my current mssql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can use MSSQL.

Actually, by default it uses SQL Express, not Access, but it can be configured for standard versions of SQL server in addition to the Express/Developer versions.

This link shows how, and it applies to newer versions of SQL Server as well.

[Configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Application Services to use SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx)